# Considering Web Socket for a JavaEE project

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, jboss, websocket, glassfish

The requirements of the project are:
If any user updates a record (any record), all relevant parties must be notified immediately by displaying an alert somewhere in the webpage. In previous projects, the browser would poll the server for any relevant changes every N seconds.

I have been reading on web sockets and think this is the prefect solution for this problem (I do not like polling).

I have some questions regarding Web Sockets in JavaEE. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Web Socket seems to be supported on Glassfish server not in latest version of JBoss/Wildfly.
2. If 1000 clients are logged in and connected to the server using Web Socket, does the server have 1000 separate sockets open for each connection? Or is the implementation similar to Node.js where a single server socket is used for all client connections. This information does not seem to be documented anywhere in JavaEE tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are TCP connections and the websocket protocol is simply an upgrade of the TCP protocol with an handshake procedure similar to the http protocol, but the websocket protocol is bidirectional.
I don't think you are getting a single web socket in Node.js. You have a connection per logged client anyway. In Node.js you have the broadcast, but this is the same as sending a message to any logged client through the related web socket. You have the same functionality in glassfish, where you simply loop on all the web sockets:

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-html5-websockets-with-multiple-clients-example

and you can do the same in weblogic:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG872

This is the same as Node.js without any wrapper.